# Is there a GUI for Squashfs-tools?

Tags: usb, kubuntu, kde, iso, squashfs

I am looking for a Gui for Squashfs-tools. I get kinda lost in the terminal, although I have the LiveCDCustomization Documentation [enter link description here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Customizations) next to it.

An alternative would be other software to manipulate the squashfs file from the ISO.

I want to get rid of some languages, fonts and some preinstalled software. I also want to rebuild more than only the Kubuntu 20.04.2 iso. I want to add updates, some programs and then update that again.

I run
Operating System:
Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-5.3-liquorix-amd64
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB

and Mint 20.2 Uma and Windows 10 on my HP Envy.

Comment: Look into using [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic)

Comment: Got it right away after I saw your comment and tried it. Gonna test the ISO I made tomorrow. Thank you so much Terrance.

Comment: I tried it with Peppermint-10-20191210-amd64. Standard there were some things highlighted. Some I did not knoww what they were, and some options I wanted to keep ( such as GParted ), so I deselected all of them. I only selected some fonts I didn't want, to try. Made the ISO. Renamed my orginal iso in Peppermint-10-20191210-amd64org and the newly created in Peppermint-10-20191210-amd64 in order to be able to boot it from my Grub2. It kernelpaniced. I give it another try with with Xubuntu. So I tried the same with Xubuntu, and it worked just fine.